# Is there an alternative to parsing a string to an integer?

Tags: java, parsing, numberformatexception

I was wondering if there was an alternative to parsing a string to an integer, because every time I use `Integer.parseInt()` I get a NumberFormatException.

My code:

```
 fileStream = new FileInputStream(pFileName);
        rdr = new InputStreamReader(fileStream);
        bufRdr = new BufferedReader(rdr);
        lineNum = 0;
        line = bufRdr.readLine();
        ArrayList<String> Objects = new ArrayList<String>(1783);

        while (line != null) {
            lineNum++;
            String[] Values = new String[13];
            Values = line.split(",");
            
            
            int cumulPos = Integer.parseInt(Values[6]);
            int cumulDec = Integer.parseInt(Values[7]);
            int cumuRec = Integer.parseInt(Values[8]);
            int curPos = Integer.parseInt(Values[9]);
            int hosp = Integer.parseInt(Values[10]);
            int intenCar = Integer.parseInt(Values[11]);
            double latitude = Double.parseDouble(Values[4]);
            double longitude = Double.parseDouble(Values[5]);

            covidrecordArray[lineNum] = new CovidRecord(Values[0], cumulPos, cumulDec, cumuRec, curPos, hosp,
                    intenCar, new Country(Values[1], Values[2], Values[3], Values[13], latitude, longitude));
```

It might be because I have empty values in my csv file which i use a buffered reader to remove, but i have tried multiple ways to remove these but it does not work so this is the only thing I can think about that will fix it.
Thanks!

Comment: Please show valid and original code. What you posted would not even compile. So the problem probably lies somewhere else. Fix your question so we can help.

Comment: If you get a `NumberFormatException`, it’s either because your string doesn’t represent a whole number or because the number it holds is out of range for `int`. In both cases the answer is no for pretty obvious reason: there isn’t any alternative way to convert that string into an `int`. You will probably want to show us an example of the data that gives the exception and also paste the full exception message into your question, probably even the stack trace (formatted as code for readability).

Comment: You certainly shouldn't charge ahead and start trying to parse empty fields as numbers. Also you need to watch your [naming](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/106-java-style-conventions)